# How to name a function which calls callback if certain conditions are met?

Tags: node.js, naming-conventions

I recently started working with nodejs. I'd like to follow the *async* nature of it and write some helper functions which take one function as an argument and call that function only if certain criteria are met, for example:

```
function areMandatoryFieldsFilledOut( fields, httpRequest, httpResponse, callback ) {
    /* some logic */
    if( mandatory_fields_have_been_filled_out ) {
        callback();
    } else {
        httpResponse.send('Mandatory fields have not been filled out!');
    }
}
// usage
areMandatoryFieldsFilledOut(['username', 'password'], req, res, function () {
    // this is executed only if both username and password values are supplied
}
```

What would be the best way write such functions? Is there a special word that You use for the beginning of the function name, like, 'ensure', e.g. '`ensureAuthenticated( callback )`?'
Is there a way to convince the reader of my code that the callback will be called only if the criteria are met just by function declaration (name and args)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existing nomenclature for this thing includes the `connect`/`express` name of `middleware` or the `Ruby on Rails` name of a `before_filter`. I use express middleware which has a very similar pattern but coupled with an ordered `stack` of functions, in which case I name these functions without any specific convention other than trying to be clear about what they do, check for, or require.

```
app.post('/submit', signedIn, authorized, formIsValid, function (req, res) { /*...code to process form.../*});
```

Sometimes I tack a `MW` on to the end if I want to make it clear this is middleware like `parseFormMW` or `supportedFormatMW`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking at this wrong. It's not the function name that needs clarification but the `callback` parameter. I would use the following function signature instead:

```
checkMandatoryFieldsFilledOut(
        fields,
        httpRequest,
        httpResponse,
        filled_out_callback
)
```

Or if that argument name feels too long I'd use `ok_callback`. If necessary I'd also give them an optional `fail_callback` in case the caller needs to do some processing if the condition fails:

```
checkMandatoryFieldsFilledOut(
        fields,
        httpRequest,
        httpResponse,
        ok_callback,
        fail_callback  /* optional */
)
```